# Formal definition of a geometric plane explained

Tags: geometry

Do any one can give a formal definition of a geometric plane and explain it?  I try to answer if any plane P in a space P is convex, but for that I need to know exactly what is a plane.

Comment: Are you talking about Euclidean Geometry? There is no definition of a point, a line, a plane.

Comment: But you can use the axioms to show this. For example, given $A,B$ on a plane $\pi$, by axiom there is only one line containing $A,B$. Since this line contains two points on the plane $\pi$ it must be contained on the plane. So the segment $AB$, that is, the plane is convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been mentioned, *planes* are primitive concepts as points and lines are, but I'm going to try here to give you a synthetic approach to complement the analytic approach given by the other solution.

If you adopt the first two groups of [Hilbert's axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms) for 2-d and 3-d geometry, then you will have enough to think about planes in the following way.

Axiom I.5 in the link states that if a line shares two points with a plane, then it is fully contained in the plane. This means if you pick $A,B$ in the plane, they describe a line (axiom I.1) which must lie fully in the plane (axiom I.5). In particular, all of the points between $A$ and $B$ lie in the plane. (We have betweeness as a primitive relation given to us in the axiom group II.) So, the line segment $AB$, which is by definition the collection of points between $A$ and $B$ and including $A$ and $B$, lies entirely in the plane.

In case you aren't familiar with Hilbert's axioms, all you need to know is that basically they are part of Hilbert's work to make Euclidean geometry rigorous. By adopting the first four groups of Hilbert's axioms, you get a system in which you can prove all of Euclidean geometry, and the axioms are independent of each other. This improved upon Euclid since some of his axioms overlapped, and he wound up (probably unknowingly) using some axioms which he did not assert, causing some gaps in a handful of proofs.

Answer (score 0):

A plane can be thought of as a set of solutions to the plane equation, generally

$ax+by+cz+d=0 $

Each solution is an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: thanks! Is an approach I didn't think about.  I keep it in mind.